# React | Multiple Context | Not able to consume default values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying out new context API released in React 16.4. I am stuck when I use multiple contexts , not able to use default values of Providers however in case of Single Contexts , Consumers able to receive default values of Providers.

Context :

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext("light");
const UserContext = React.createContext({ name: "Guest" });`
```

**Providers**

```
 <ThemeContext.Provider>
        <UserContext.Provider>
          <Main />
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
```

**Consumers**:

```
 <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {theme => (
        <UserContext.Consumer>
          {user => <ProfilePage user={user} theme={theme} />}
        </UserContext.Consumer>
      )}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
```

Please find the sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/6w8qn7yy4k

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the React docs:

> The `defaultValue` argument is only used by a `Consumer` when it does
>   not have a matching `Provider` above it in the tree.

```
// context
const ThemeContext = React.createContext("light");
const UserContext = React.createContext({ name: "Guest" });

function Content() {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {theme => <ProfilePage theme={theme} />}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  );
}


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider>
        <Main />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The above code doesn't have a provider for ThemeContext and hence its takes the default value.

If you use both providers you need to supply the value to all the providers like

```
<ThemeContext.Provider value={"light"}>
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ name: "Guest" }}>
      <Main />
    </UserContext.Provider>
 </ThemeContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default values passed in the `createContext()` call will only be given to consumers if there are no matching `<Provider/>` components in your render tree.

In the CodeSandBox example, your `<App />` component renders both `<Provider />` components, but does not pass the `value` prop, this results in an undefined value.

I updated your CodeSandBox to only render the `<Content />` component. Notice how the default values work now :) https://codesandbox.io/s/j207ollx89